# c# stream writer: how to write numbers on new lines?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

i want to make  stream writer function where i can write numbers several times and at the end of the program  show me sum of those numbers. how i can code this thing?

```
public static void bought(float a)
    {
        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ETN\source\repos\Apple-store\Apple-store\buy.txt");
        SW.Write(a);
        SW.Close();

    }
```

Comment: first you'll probably need to make your parameter an array or collection

Comment: how? i am bad at stream writer function, can you help me?i dont know how many numbers will be using

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide some context? What is it you want to do (in a broader sense) and why?

Comment: `new StreamWriter(@"....", append: true)`  and `SW.WriteLine(a)`

Comment: thank you guys!!! i am creating some console store  i want to save numbers if costumer bought it and i want to calling out this method and save several numbers but  it is uknown amount and at the end i want to show sum of those numbers

Comment: What are the numbers? Prices? Quantities? Something else? To get meaningful responses it is recommended to be as specific as possible. It is also recommended to add this information to the queston (via the edit link at its bottom). Remember that people here don't know what you want to do. The more you explain the more likely you will get help.

Comment: dear  Nick.McDermaid i was searching solution 2 days but i couldnt arrange to make this code. if you can make alone with google stackoverflow is not needed at all

Comment: hi sefe those number are prices but i need to save them by float value and at the and i can write $ symbol

Comment: huge thank you  i add append and it works i also changed SW.WriteLine(a) to SW.WriteLine(" " + a) for free space and now i want to add all those numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you would want to change in your code. Speficially:

- You are opening a stream writer, write *one* value and close it. Unless you already have a list of values you want to write, you generally open and close the stream writer *once* and call it multiple times.
- When you want to add a new line after your written value, you use `WriteLine` instead of `Write`.
- When you write numeric values to a text file, they will be converted to text dependent on the culture. Note that the default is the culture of your system. If you read the file from a different computer with a different culture, the file might be unreadable. Therefore you should always provide a specific culture. To do that, check the `Convert.ToString` method.
- You should enclose your code that writes to the stream writer in a `try`/`finally` block, with the `StreamWriter.Close()` method in the `finally`. Otherwise your file is not guaranteed to be closed in the event of an error.
- It is not recommended to store monetary information (such as prices or account balances) as a `float`. Use `decimal` instead, which is optimized for this purpose (as opposed to `float` which is for scientific calculations).

This code should give you a head start at the issue. It's up to you to complete it and organize it into methods, classes etc., depending on your specific requirements:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ETN\source\repos\Apple-store\Apple-store\buy.txt");
try {
    while (true) {
        decimal price:
        //Your code that determines the price goes here
        string priceText = Convert.ToString(price, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        writer.WriteLine(priceText);

        bool shouldContinue;
        //Your code that determines whether there are more values to be written goes here
        if (!shouldContinue) {
            break;
        }
    }
    writer.Flush();
}
finally {
    writer.Close();
}
```